# Angular JS $http request does not reach the server in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, angularjs

I'm having issues with using $http on ie8. The request does not reach the server, until I hit a refresh. Coming back to the same link still has the same problem until I hit refresh again.

The weird thing is if the web server is on LAN and the request is made to a server in LAN, it works fine. But if the webserver is hosted remotely, it does not work!

Here is the code:

**Index.html**

```
{{test}}
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller(
    "TestController",
    function( $scope, $http) {
        var url = '/test/get_data';
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            $scope.test = data;
        });
    }
);
```

I got this error: **TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or methodundefined**

I prepared a JSFiddle earlier but JSFiddle is broken in ie8 so I don't provide it here.

Unfortunately I don't have a remote server that I can share with you.

**Edit**
Previously I used an external url which gave me 'Access Denied' error in ie because of Same Origin Policy as mentioned by one answer below. But this was not my original problem. I still have the issue above when request is from the same origin

Comment: what is the response data, and whether the request is reaching the server

Comment: the request is not reaching the server but it does if I hit a refresh. Coming back to the same link still has the same problem until I hit refresh again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the fix... Hope this helps anyone out there that experience this problem

1. Angular script needs to be loaded after jQuery. I didn't have this because Yii framework that I use autoloads jQuery and the angular was not included after the jQuery.
2. All the controller functions need to be at the end of body section (just before the closing )
3. Updating to angular 1.0.5 seems to fix the problem. The problem occurred in 1.0.4 with all the above tricks. I think is related to fix [791804bd](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/791804bdbfa6da7a39283623bd05628a01cd8720)

Answer (score 1):

This is a cross domain request, which is not allowed in ajax because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

There are two solutions for this
1. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP): It is a cross browser way to handle cross domain ajax requests using javascript callback mechanism
2. [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing): It is a HTML5 standard, it is implemented by most of the modern browsers except IE

Mongodb lab is not supporting jsonp since it has support for CORS, that is why your request is failing in IE and works in Chrome and other browsers.

As per [this post](https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20676708-JSONP-support) they do not have any plan to support jsonp, so I don't thick there is a way to make this work in IE.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry I just updated my question. The error was still there even the request came from the same origin